# SQL varaibles if statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a issue resulting in the following error.

```
declare @transDate datetime = GETDATE();
declare @main_work_center as varchar(50) = 'PMOM';
declare @team as varchar(1) = '';
declare @full_work_center as varchar(50);
IF(@team = '' OR @team IS NULL) then
    @full_work_center = @main_work_center;
else
    @full_work_center = @main_work_center + @team;
end if
```

THis is the error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'then'.

Comment: `then` is not used in SQL Server after `if`.  The error message seems quite clear.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple syntax errors in your code, that's just the first.

1. `then` is not allowed with an `if`
2. You need a `set` before your variable assignments in the `if`/`else`
3. There is no `if` after the `end`

I like to wrap the code inside the two blocks of an `if`/`else` with `begin` and `end`, much like the curly braces in other languages, for clarity.

Fully corrected code:

```
declare @transDate datetime = GETDATE();
declare @main_work_center as varchar(50) = 'PMOM';
declare @team as varchar(1) = '';
declare @full_work_center as varchar(50);
IF(@team = '' OR @team IS NULL) 
begin
    set @full_work_center = @main_work_center;
end
else
begin
    set @full_work_center = @main_work_center + @team;
end;
```